# How to reply status as server busy from tcp server in c#

Tags: c#, serversocket

I have a client(Windows app) and server(Class file) both dose not implement multi threading.
So now I have is one to one connection working fine but when second client tries to connect nothing happens and when i try to communicate it goes un responding.

But I want this functionality in it:

When second client tries to connect the server should reply status as busy to second client. I want to put code some where in server that will reply the second client by checking the status of the server.

How can I achieve this?

Provided complete code below for better understanding:
**Server code**

```
enum ServerStatus { Available, Busy };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener tcplistener = null;
        ServerStatus serverstatus = ServerStatus.Available;
        try
        {
            tcplistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4000);
            tcplistener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server socket started at 127.0.0.1 and port no: 4000");
            Console.WriteLine("Server is " + serverstatus + " and waiting for a client to connect....");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient tcpclient = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();
                serverstatus = ServerStatus.Busy;
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "New client connection started and server is " + serverstatus);
                StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(tcpclient.GetStream());
                StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(tcpclient.GetStream());
                String datafromclient = String.Empty;
                String datatoclient = String.Empty;
                while (!(datafromclient = streamreader.ReadLine()).Equals(String.Empty))
                {
                    int number;
                    if (int.TryParse(datafromclient, out number))
                    {
                        datatoclient = (Convert.ToInt16(datafromclient) * Convert.ToInt16(datafromclient)).ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("From client -> " + datafromclient + "   To client -> " + datatoclient);
                        streamwriter.WriteLine(datatoclient);
                        streamwriter.Flush();
                    }
                    else if (datafromclient == "End connection")
                    {
                        streamreader.Close();
                        streamwriter.Close();
                        serverstatus = ServerStatus.Available;
                        Console.WriteLine("Server is back to " + serverstatus + " and waiting for a client to connect....");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        streamwriter.WriteLine("Number not valid.");
                        streamwriter.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tcplistener != null)
            {
                tcplistener.Stop();
            }
        }
```

**Client side code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tcpclient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 4000);
            if (tcpclient != null)
            {
                label1.Text = "Connected to server";
                textBox1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
                streamreader = new StreamReader(tcpclient.GetStream());
                streamwriter = new StreamWriter(tcpclient.GetStream());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number))
        {
            streamwriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            streamwriter.Flush();
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "To server -> " + textBox1.Text + "     From server -> " + streamreader.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid number.");
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        streamwriter.WriteLine("End connection");
        streamwriter.Flush();
        streamreader.Close();
        streamwriter.Close();
        tcpclient.Close();
        label1.Text = "Disconnected to server";
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if your application is single threaded, you can not respond to something while that one thread is doing something else...

you have 2 options:

a) multithreading, and having some other thread responding while in busy state
b) don't keep your thread in a hot loop: which is most likely what you want to do

you may be want to read this: https://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/creating-a-single-threaded-multi-user-tcp-server-in-net/

Comment: Right now it will accepts second client once the first client is disconnected. This is achieved by using that infinity loop. my doubt is if second client tries toconnects will this line TcpClient tcpclient = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient(); is over written by new client or not because the infinity while loop is still running?

Comment: I would go with "a". After accepting a client, create a new thread for that client and start it. By doing so you will be ready to handle the second client almost instantly

Comment: AcceptTcpClient() will accept the connection and give you the corresponding client object ... if you overwrite something with it, that's your decision ... you could put it into a collection instead, and regularily check if one of the connected clients has data....